# configure gunicorn to work with sandbox django-oscar

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, django-oscar

I download Django-oscar & install it with (make sandbox)
the runserver works fine

for deployment

I copy the latest.wsgi file to sandbox folder & rename it wsgi.py

I also edit it

```
# Project root
root = '/home/test/oscaruni/django-oscar-releases-0.7/sites/sandbox'
sys.path.insert(0, root)

# Packages from virtualenv
activate_this = '/home/test/oscaruni/django-oscar-releases-0.7/oscar/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

then

```
(oscar)test@debian:~/oscaruni/django-oscar-releases-0.7/sites/sandbox$ gunicorn wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8001
```

blinking cursor remains in the command line

How I configure gunicorn to work with sandbox django-oscar ?

Comment: I install gunicorn on fresh django with gunicorn 19.0 the same problem occurred but with gunicorn 18.0 every thing goes fine so I will stick with 18.0